# Testing signed cookies in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm using signed cookies in Rails 3 to enable a "remember-me" feature in an application. Everything works except I'm not able to functional test the cookies, since comparing `cookies['remember_id']` gives me the encrypted cookie, and `cookies.signed` is not defined.

Any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem (at least on the surface) is that in the context of a functional test (ActionController::TestCase), the "cookies" object is a Hash, whereas when you work with the controllers, it's a ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar object.  So we need to convert it to a CookieJar object so that we can use the "signed" method on it to convert it to a SignedCookieJar.

You can put the following into your functional tests (after a get request) to convert cookies from a Hash to a CookieJar object

```
@request.cookies.merge!(cookies)
cookies = ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build(@request)
```

Comment: I came across this same problem, so thanks! I was wondering if it is necessary to include these two lines multiple times, if in the same test a new/second request is made thereby generating new cookies? Would it be possible to turn it into a test helper (with cookies as a parameter)?

Comment: The method `merge!` is deprecated in Rails 5. What would be the right code in Rails 5? (if I'm not mistaken `merge` is still available)

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly off-topic, but I was having trouble getting the Rails 3 solution to work in Rails 5 because ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build has changed.  This did the trick:

```
jar = ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build(@request, cookies.to_hash)
assert_equal jar.signed['remember_token'], ...
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but posting an answer that is "slightly off topic" might warrant making a comment on the question rather than posting an answer.  :)

Comment: I wanted to, but you have to have a rep > 50 to comment on someone else's question or answer. Which I don't as it's my first post :)

Comment: Good call Bill. Thanks for that insight.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert all encrypted and signed cookies to the regular ones for test environment. Just make sure you don't have cookies with `secure` attribute (won't work)

In `config/initializers/signed_cookies_patch_test.rb`:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  class ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar
    def encrypted; self; end
    def signed; self; end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

assert_equal @controller.send(:cookies).signed[:remember_id], matching_value